# mysql LEF JOIN with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables:

games:

```
g_id | country | team_1 | team_2
--------------------------------
  1  | England | Bayern | Chelsea
  2  | England | Bayern | Liverp
  3  | England | Bayern | Ajax
```

statistic:

```
s_id | s_time | s_name   | g_id
-----------------------------
 1   |   4    | Alen A.  |  1
 2   |   7    | Dagn S.  |  1
 3   |   11   | Eden D.  |  1
 4   |   22   | Aren A.  |  1
 5   |   8    | Falen B. |  2
 6   |   66   | Poker G. |  2
 7   |   76   | Nuker S. |  2
 8   |   87   | Eben Y.  |  2
 9   |   18   | Falen B. |  3
 10  |   19   | Aalen F. |  3
 11  |   33   | Gased G. |  3
 12  |   44   | Halen B. |  3
```

And i'm trying to get data from 2 tables with left join where limit

here a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games
LEFT JOIN statistic
ON games.g_id = statistic.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Bayern'
LIMIT 2
```

result is:

```
g_id | country | team_1 | team_2 | s_id | s_time | s_name   | g_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  1   |   4    | Alen A.  |  1
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  2   |   7    | Dags S.  |  1
```

i need all data from statistics with limit 2 from table "games"! here example what i need:

```
g_id | country | team_1 | team_2 | s_id | s_time | s_name   | g_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  1   |   4    | Alen A.  |  1
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  2   |   7    | Dags S.  |  1
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  3   |   11   | Eden D.  |  1
 1   | England | Bayern | Chelsea|  4   |   22   | Aren A.  |  1
 2   | England | Bayern | Liverp |  5   |   8    | Falen B. |  2
 2   | England | Bayern | Liverp |  6   |   66   | Dags S.  |  2
 2   | England | Bayern | Liverp |  7   |   76   | Alen A.  |  2
 2   | England | Bayern | Liverp |  8   |   87   | Dags S.  |  2
```

What query i need?

Comment: Why do you want to use limit instead of g_id<=2?  It's unlikely limit is the best way to get what you need.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor *Bayern team can be random in table not first 2*.

Comment: normalize data. just a thot

Comment: Well it depends on how you want the query to pick which two games.  I know mysql isn't good with a lot of nested queries so maybe limit is the best.  That being said, unless g_id is sorted in such a way to give you the two you want you'll need to think of how you want to select which games before anyone can help incorporate that into your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM games WHERE team1 = 'Bayern' ORDER BY g_id LIMIT 2) AS g
LEFT JOIN statistic AS s
ON g.g_id = s.g_id
```

Comment: ** Bayern team can be random in table not first 2